# Instantiate objects using a helper class

Tags: java, oop, object

I want to create an instance of my object, car. The problem I have is that i can create an instance of the car object such as, Car car1 = new car("Audi","A4","BF10YMR"); however I want to create car objects through a helper class. How do I call this helper class in main so that is of type car and not of type carHelper?

The car object requires a random registration number to be created and this is created in the carHelper class. The object is returned.

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car>
{
   public class Car
   {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String registration;  

   public Car(String make, String model, String reg)
   {
   this.make= make;
   this.model= model;
   registration = reg;
   }
}

public class carHelper
{
  public car genCar()
  {
    String reg =   //some method to generate random registration.
    String Make =  //some method to randomly pick make from a list
    String model = //some method to randomly pick model from a list
    return new Car(make,model,registration);
   }
 } 

public class Garage
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
    Garage MyGarage = new Garage(); 
    Car car1 = new Car("Audi","A4","BF10YMR") //works, but doesn't use helper                                                                       
    Car car2 = carHelper.genCar();   // something like this?

    carHelper c = new carHelper();   // thought something like this but
    System.out.println(c.genCar());  // creates object of type carHelper 
                                     // not car.

   MyGarage.add(car1); 
   MyGarage.add(car2);   // gives me carHelper cannot be converted to Car

   }
}

public class GarageOp implements CarList
{
  public GarageOp()
  {
   list = new ArrayList<Car>(); 
  }

public boolean add(Car car) 
{
  if (list.contains(car) == false)
  {
     list.add(car); 
     return true;
  }
}
```

}

Expected result is create car object using the helper class and add it to an ArrayList.

Comment: `c.genCar()` **does** create a `car`. Please change your `car` class to start with an upper case char, same goes for `carHelper`: `Car` and `CarHelper`, only variables, fields and methods start with lower case chars

Comment: Seems you are trying to get to what the factory pattern generally does.

Comment: Java naming conventions: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: i just wrote this now, not my actual code, just a plan showing my problem

Comment: And, once i try and add car1 and car2 to an arraylist, i get carHelper cannot be converted to type car.

Comment: @Fusiozii The code you've shown us here will work correctly.  It will generate a `car` and not a `carHelper`.  Since this isn't your actual code, can you provide us with a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Car car2 = carHelper.genCar();   // something like this?    
For this to work **genCar** has to be **static**    
    carHelper c = new carHelper();   // thought something like this but    
**c** is of type **carHelper**    
    System.out.println(c.genCar());    
**c.genCar** returns an object of type **Car** but what you print to the console is just it's reference!    
All the clean code violations aside, you should first understand [Object Oriented Programming][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming] or even more basic programming concepts like data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create this lists in the CarHelper and than, randomly, select the values and create a new Car with them. The UUID creates a random 128 bits (including hex) number and converts to a String

```
public class CarHelper {

    private List<String> makeList = Arrays.asList("s", "t", "f", "n");
    private List<String> modelList = Arrays.asList("yyt", "32g", "dc3", "aas");

    public Car genCar() {
        String reg = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String make = makeList.get(new Random().nextInt(makeList.size() - 1));
        String model = modelList.get(new Random().nextInt(modelList.size() - 1));
        return new Car(make,model,reg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but i've already got this, just gave a quick description of my problem :)

Answer (score -2):

Make the genCar() method as Static in the CarHelper class.

```
public car static genCar(){
    // do stuff to create object
}
```

a non-static method can access a static variable or call a static method in Java.

Comment: and that changes *what* exactly?